# Hash declaration syntax error in irb

Tags: ruby

```
1. { :a => 10 } #=> no error
2. { a: 10 }    #=> no error

3. { :"str" => 10 } #=> no error
4. { "str": 10 }    #=> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
```

Isn't 4. same as 2? Why 2 is working and 4 throws syntax error?

Comment: Can somebody explain which part of the question qualifies to receive a downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that `{"key": value}` is not a valid syntax as it is not clear whether it means `{:"key" => value}` or `{"key" => value}`

There is a discussion on this [here](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4801). Quote from Matz in the discussion

> | Iff  {'key': 'value'} means {:key => 'value'} I have no objection.
>
> | Won't that be misleading? I think the OP wants {'key': 'value'} to mean {'key' => 'value}
>
> But considering the fact that {key: "value"}
>   is a shorthand for {:key => "value"}, {"key": "value"} should be a
>   shorthand for {:"key" => "value"}.  Besides that, since it reminds me
>   JSON so much, making a: and "a": different could cause more confusion
>   than the above misleading.
>
> ```
>           matz.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**[`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html): Hashes allow an alternate syntax form when your keys are always symbols.**

```
options = { :font_size => 10, :font_family => "Arial" }
```

You could write it as:

```
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
```

In your first 3 cases all are symbols in key position,but the fourth is a string instance,not the symbol instance as key.That's the reason 4th case is invalid Ruby syntax.

```
{ :a => 10 }.keys[0].class # => Symbol
{ a: 10 }.keys[0].class    # => Symbol
{ :"str" => 10 }.keys[0].class # => Symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

No. (1) is standard symbol, (2) is shorthand 1.9 syntax for symbol-key hashes, (3) is shorthand for "str".to_sym, (4) does not exist and you should use the hashrocket.